# How to export Next Best Action Recommendations?

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, einstein-next-best-action

We have created lots of Recommendations in our sandbox, for use in Next Best Action. Now that we are satisfied with how this works, we want to export them to our production org. How can we do that?

It is not possible to create a report type for Recommendations:

[image]

I myself have the proper Next Best Action related permissions, but for some reason that is not enough to create a report on Recommendations.

So, who knows how to create a Recommendations report or another way of transporting them to the production org?